# Is there a way to get a list of what has been installed from a specific repository?

Tags: raspbian

In the past I have adapted /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/preferences to be able to install packages both from wheezy and jessie, but would like to undo some of those jessie imports because they are no longer necessary (e.g. the ones related to openssl/heartbleed)

I do know the toplevel packages that I installed from Jessie, but have no idea what was installed at the same time to meet the dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Trying to find a solution, I came up with two ways to get the information I want.

**Method 1**:
I created two awk scripts (which I could publish somehow if there is interest).

The first awk script takes the output of `apt-cache dump` (which produces detailed info about all packages in the currently sourced repositories) and reformats the info into 2 separate text files: `scan-jessie.log` (containing a single package/version line for all packages in the Jessie repository), and `scan-wheezy.log` (containing a single package/version line of all packages in the Wheezy repository).

The second awk script takes the output of `dpkg -l` (which produces info about all packages currently installed in the system), extracts the package/version fields from it and using the two files created by the first step, prepends the name of the repository they originate from and outputs the result to `stdout` (to allow the use of `grep` or `less`)

running
    `sudo apt-cache dump | awk -f scan-repo.awk`
    `sudo dpkg -l        | awk -f scan-dpkg.awk | grep jessie`

produces (on my system) the following output

```
jessie dosfstools 3.0.26-3
jessie init 1.20
jessie init-system-helpers 1.20
jessie libc-dev-bin 2.19-7
jessie libc6 2.19-7
jessie libc6-dev 2.19-7
jessie libnih-dbus1 1.0.3-4.3
jessie libnih1 1.0.3-4.3
jessie libssl1.0.0 1.0.1i-1
jessie locales 2.19-7
jessie sysvinit-core 2.88dsf-53.3
```

**Method 2**:
While scanning the Debian documentation related to 'Pinning' using `/etc/apt/preferences` and `/etc/apt/sources.list`, I came about the use of the Pin-priority, to force the downgrade of a package.

In my case, I had the following setup:

`/etc/apt/preferences:`

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=wheezy
Pin-Priority: 900

Package: *
Pin: release n=jessie
Pin-Priority: 300

Package: *
Pin: release o=Raspbian
Pin-Priority: -10`
```

By **temporarily** changing the priority of the Wheezy packages to **1001**, like so

```
Package: *
Pin: release n=wheezy
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release n=jessie
Pin-Priority: 300

Package: *
Pin: release o=Raspbian
Pin-Priority: -10
```

`sudo apt-get upgrade` produces the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  dosfstools libssl1.0.0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 downgraded, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,118 kB of archives.
After this operation, 74.8 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`
produces the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  init-system-helpers sysvinit sysvinit-core
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libcryptsetup4 libpam-systemd libsystemd-daemon0 libsystemd-id128-0 
  libsystemd-journal0 systemd systemd-sysv
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  dosfstools libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6-dev libnih-dbus1 libnih1 libssl1.0.0 locales
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing!
  sysvinit
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 8 downgraded, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 15.4 MB of archives.
After this operation, 2,661 kB of additional disk space will be used.
You are about to do something potentially harmful.
To continue type in the phrase 'Yes, do as I say!'
```

These last two `apt-get` runs do not explicitly say that the packages that will be removed/downgraded came from **Jessie**, but since **Wheezy** is the fallback/master, I think one may assume that they came from the Jessie repository.

Anyhow, both methods provide similar information about what will be removed/downgraded (additionally the pin method also shows what will be installed new)

Method 2, starting an `apt-get dist-upgrade` with a Pin-Priority of 1001 (**without** actually executing it) seems to be quite useful and most importantly: **built-in !**

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the toplevel packages you installed, you may want to take a look at history logs in `/var/log/apt/history.log.{#}.gz`.  The log will show you the command used to install the toplevel packages, as well as the complete list of dependencies, along with versions.

Here is a sample entry:

`Start-Date: 2012-12-15  17:42:19
Commandline: apt-get install -y libraspberrypi-bin libraspberrypi0 raspberrypi-bootloader
Install: libraspberrypi0:armhf (1.20121025-1), raspberrypi-bootloader:armhf (1.20121025-1), libraspberrypi-bin:armhf (1.20121025-1)
End-Date: 2012-12-15  17:42:42`

Comment: The information contained in these log files is very helpful in finding out when-and-why packages got installed in the past. Thanks for the tip !